# How to give two representations of dto based on http parameter?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm trying to write GET which will return response with basic or full set of parameters.

For example. Request to this url

```
localhost:8080/resource?&outputSchema=basic
```

Should return

```
{
    "total": 5
}
```

But this request

```
localhost:8080/resource?&outputSchema=extended
```

Should return more data

```
{
    "total": 5,
    "name": "John"
}
```

How can one send different response in spring based on request parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have found an answer. For `@RequestMapping` one should use `params` parameter to filter by desired parameter value.

For example one endpoint would look like this

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "outputSchema=basic", produces = {"application/json"})
public @ResponseBody MyResponse1 findSomeResource(
        @RequestParam(value = "outputSchema", required = true) String outputSchema) {
    return new MyResponse1();
}
```

and for the second one

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "outputSchema=extended", produces = {"application/json"})
public String test() {
    return "Different response";
}
```